# How to add a RecyclerView to Navigation in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am working on task managing app on Android and would like users be able to click "+" button in navigation so that they can add a new project whenever they need and in such way that a new project appears in navigation immediately that can be used to access only tasks of this project.

I wanted to do this using a RecyclerView and adapter to fill items in navigation, but this didn't work out.

Can you tell me how should I implement this using a RecyclerView or something else?
An example of how I would like it to look like is from [Google Task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29tD5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add RecyclerView inside NavigationView and Add your task list into RecyclerView.
You can easily perform click Item click of RecyclerView.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/navigationList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Note: 
When you click item of RecyclerView you must close NavigationDrawer.